# Runtime analysis clarification

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, analysis, logarithm

Just for clarification. If you have an algorithm that calls 3 different functions. Each of these functions has a runtime of logn. The runtime of the algorithm is bigO(log n) correct? The definition of bigO being f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n. For this situation. we could look at c as 3 for the 3 functions and g(n) being logn?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the algorithm calls these functions. If the algorithm looks like

`function algorithm(input) {
    f(input'); // size of input' = O(size of input)
    g(input''); // size of input'' = (size of input)
    h(input'''); // size of input''' = O(size of input)
}`

then the running time is the sum of running times of the functions the algorithm calls. Thus if `f`, `g`, and `h` run in time `O(log n)` then the algorithm also runs in time `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your function is `f(n)` and the 3 functions it calls are `f_1(n), f_2(n)` and `f_3(n)`. Let also `T(f(n))` be the running time of `f(n)`.

If for any `i`, function `f_i(n)` has running time `O(log(n))`, then it means by the definition, that there exist `c_i > 0` and `n_i >= 0`, such that for all `n >= n_i`, `T(f_i(n)) <= c_i * log(n)`.

From the above fact, in order to proof that `T(f(n))` is also `O(log(n))`, you just need to find the constants `n0 >= 0, c > 0`, such that for all `n >= n0`, `T(f(n)) <= c * log(n)`.

It turns out that if you pick `n0 = max(n_1, n_2, n_3)`, and `c = 3 * max(c_1, c_2, c_3)`, the condition is fullfilled, so indeed `T(f(n)) = O(log(n))`. This is sufficient, because we know that the only thing `f(n)` does is that it calls `f_1(n), f_2(n)` and `f_3(n)`, and each of these functions is called exactly once.